# would it be same to make a GET request in nodejs instead of redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, redirect

Would it be different if i make a GET request from modulefn to example.com with same params instead of redirect?

Lets say res is making a rediect to example.com like-

```
app.all(/testurl,(req, res) => {

  params = req.body.x_params

  res.redirect("example.com?" + params)

}
```

Comment: A redirect is just going to tell the client to do it's own GET request so either way the GET request is happening.  Beyond explaining that, it's unclear what you're really asking here.  It's your programming choice whether you want the client to do its own GET or you want to do it on their behalf.  Telling the client to do its own GET is more efficient for your server, but more work to use your API.

Comment: I want the client to do it's GET request but he is having some issues getting the params so on behalf of the client i want to test the client endpoint      "/testurl" is basiclly client's endpoint and client will do a follow up GET reuqest with some data to my server @jfriend00

Comment: If you control the client or can tell the client what to do, you could just return JSON that includes the parameters and the URL you want them to go to and the client could do that to do their own GET.  Probably `req.body.x_params` is not formatted appropriately to go in your redirect URL.